# how to compare two tables fields name with another value in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables

1. table_school

   ```
   school_open_time|school_close_time|school_day
   8:00 AM         | 9:00PM          | Monday
   10:00 AM        | 7:00PM          | Wednesday
   ```
2. table_college

   ```
    college_open_time|college_close_time|college_day    
    10:00 AM         | 8:00PM           | Monday
    10:00 AM         | 9:00PM           | Tuesday
    10:00 AM         | 5:00PM           | Wednesday
   ```

Now I want to select `school_open_time` `school_close time`, `college_open_time` and `college_close_time` according to today (means `college_day=school_day=today`), and also if there is no row for a specific day in any of one table then it display blank field ( `LEFT JOIN` , I think I can use).

Please suggest me best and optimized query for this.

**UPDATE:**

if there is no open time and close time for school then college_open_time and college_close_time has to be returned( not to be filled in database,just return) as school_open_time and school_close_time. and there always must be college_open_time and college_close_time for a given day

---

i m using below query

```
 SELECT college_open_time,college_close_time ,school_open_time,
        school_close_time  FROM tbl_college
 LEFT JOIN tbl_school ON school_owner_id=college_owner_id 
 WHERE college_owner_id='".$_session['user_id']."' AND
 college_day='".date('l',time())."'";
```

it return single row (left hand having some value and right hand having blank value) when there is no row of a given day in table_school, BUT display seven rows with same value on left hand side(college_open_time, college_close_time) and 6 blank row on right hand side (school_open_time and school_close_time)

```
i need only one row when both table have a row of a given day
```

but using above query take only first row of corresponding table_school where school_owner_id is 50(let), it not see the condition that school_day name should be given day

---

**More UPDATE @37Stars**

There is a little bit problem also Dear,
datatype of school_close_time and school_open time is `TIME` type
whereas datatype of college_open_time and college_close_time is `VARCHAR` type. 
i used below code given by you but i modified a bit and i m getting close to result,

but now tell me where i have to write IFNULL in below code segment

***IFNULL(TIME_FORMAT()) Or TIME_FORMAT(IFNULL())***

```
SELECT TC.owner_id,college_open_time AS collegeOpen, 
       college_close_time AS collegeClose, 
TIME_FORMAT(school_open_time, '%h:%i %p' ) AS schoolOpen,       
TIME_FORMAT(school_close_time, '%h:%i %p' ) AS schoolClose
FROM tbl_college TC
LEFT JOIN tbl_school  TS ON TS.owner_id = TC.owner_id
AND TC.college_day = TS.school_day
WHERE college_day = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%W')
```

---

**Solution**

Thanks 37stars, u r genious, thanx for the ideo of IFNULL,

*i m writing OPTIMUM AND BEST QUERY*

```
SELECT TC.owner_id,college_open_time AS collegeOpen,college_close_time AS 
    collegeClose, IFNULL(TIME_FORMAT(school_open_time, '%h:%i %p'),college_open_time) 
    AS schoolOpen,IFNULL(TIME_FORMAT(school_close_time, '%h:%i %p',college_close_time)
    AS schoolClose FROM tbl_college TC LEFT JOIN tbl_school TS 
    ON TS.owner_id = TC.owner_id AND TC.college_day = TS.school_day 
    WHERE college_day = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%W') 
    FROM tbl_storecalendar TS LEFT JOIN tbl_delivery_hours TD 
    ON TD.store_id = TS.store_id 
    AND TD.del_day = TS.dayName WHERE dayName = DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%W' )
```

Comment: Is there always exactly one or none record in table\_school and table\_college for a given day?

Comment: `colelge_day`? Is that actually the column name, or was it just a typo in the question?

Comment: there is alwayz one row for a given day specified by `school_id` and `college_id`

Comment: I believe it was a typo, since every other occurrence of *college* was spelled correctly.

Comment: @I Like PHP: doesn't your update to the question directly contradict your previous statement 'and also if there is no row for a specific day in any of one table then it display blank field'? How is it possible to fulfil both of those statements at once?

Comment: @I Like PHP: What if there is no college_open_time and no college_close_time, but there is a school_open_time and school_close_time?

Comment: i have edited my question, please see and thank you for remind me such type of condition. i"ll think abt it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add **school_day = college_day** to your JOIN clause.

```
SELECT college_open_time, college_close_time, school_open_time, school_close_time
FROM dbo.tbl_college AS TC
    LEFT JOIN dbo.tbl_school AS TS ON TS.owner_id = TC.owner_id 
    AND TS.school_day = TC.college_day
WHERE TC.owner_id = 1 
    AND college_day = 'tuesday'
```

Comment: i want to know all owner's college day and school day time..not single one which have owdner id=1

Comment: i have also written that if some day there is no school open time and school close time then college open time and college close time should be returned as school open time and school close time.....
please read my question once again.

Comment: Ah easy enough. 

Remove the owner_id from the where clause.

And use:

select ifnull(school_open_time, college_open_time), ifnull(school_close_time, college_close_time), college_open_time, school_close_time

Comment: Thanks 37 stars, thankx for solution and giving me idea of IFNULL
i have updated the optimum query in SOLUTION SECTION OF  in my question

Answer (score 4):

You want a FULL OUTER JOIN, but unfortunately MySQL doesn't support this. Luckily, there is a workaround by combining a left join and a right join using `UNION ALL`:

Update: Changed query to answer OP's updated question.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(school_day, college_day) AS day,
    COALESCE(school_open_time, college_open_time) AS school_open_time,
    COALESCE(school_close_time, college_close_time) AS school_close_time,
    COALESCE(college_open_time, school_open_time) AS college_open_time,
    COALESCE(college_close_time, school_close_time) AS college_close_time
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table_school LEFT JOIN table_college ON school_day = college_day
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM table_school RIGHT JOIN table_college ON school_day = college_day
    WHERE school_day IS NULL
) AS T1
```

Comment: I did not know that mysql had a `COALESCE`, that's good to know.

Comment: @RAHUL PRASAD if the first parameter of COALESCE is null it returns the second parameter

Comment: @Patrick: More specifically, returns the first of its parameters which differs from NULL. You can write for example COALECSE(column1, column2, column3, column4).

Comment: @Tobias Yes you re right, i should have says that it returns the first non null parameters ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend changing your DB structure to two tables with the following structure:

`table institutions:

institution | institution_id

table times:

institution_id | day | open_time | close_time`

You could easily put your two existing tables into the new times table, i.e.

`INSERT INTO times(institution, day, open_time, close_time)

SELECT 'School', school_day, school_open_time, school_close_time

FROM table_school`

And then getting the query results is easy:

`SELECT i.institution, t.open_time, t.close_time

FROM times t

  LEFT JOIN institutions i on t.institution_id=i.institution_id

WHERE day='Wednesday'`

Comment: i can't do this , bcoz both tables are on some id which is common in both table like owner id, and 
i want to know school and college's timing for a specific owner

Comment: Just add owner_id to the institutions table (i.e. one owner for each institution).  Whenever you have two tables that are as similar as yours (each one has a day, an open time, and a close time) your data model needs to reflect that by putting the info in one db table.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to accomplish this in one query, you'll have to use `UNION` to put your results together, like this:

```
SELECT school_open_time AS openTime,`int` AS school_close_time
    FROM table_school WHERE school_day=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%W')
UNION
SELECT college_open_time AS openTime,`int` AS college_close_time
    FROM table_college WHERE college_day=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%W');
```

Where `DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%W')` converts to the current day of the week.

However, this method doesn't seem all that great to me.  First of all, it won't handle putting NULL methods into the result set for you in the case of a missing record.  You could add some IF/ELSE statements to do this for you, but in all honesty, I'd probably just make two separate queries from your PHP code.  That way, you can handle each one specifically and control your results more easily from there.